# how to update only a some field of an entity in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user table. In that table I have different fields. I only need to update the image column of the user table.

I have a form for uploading the image only. Even though the image is set but when I submit the form I get validations errors of other fields.

I know that the validation errors are because I passed the user object to the form and issued a isValid().

How do I only update the specific column like the image column?

```
public function updateImageAction(Request $request){

        $form = $this->createForm(new UploadImageType(),new User(),[
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('update_image')
        ]);


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $data = $form->getData();

            dump($data);die;

            $em->persist($data);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('photo.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView()

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Probably want validation groups: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups

Comment: You are not updating an existing user in this code sample, you are creating the new one. If that's correct, take a look at validation groups, as @cerad says.

If you have an issue with nullifying user's properties because they are not present in POST data, you may want to use `$form->submit($request->request->all(), false)` instead of `$form->handleRequest($request)`.

Comment: Validation groups are different topic. The comment from @kozlice about setting the clearMissing argument to false is the right answer

Comment: @kozlice Could you take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381691/symfony-3-form-model-data-loses-property-values-which-are-not-represented-by-f). When I use `$form->submit($request->request->all(), false)` like you suggested I do not even get any data...