# Symfony 3 - Form model data loses property values which are not represented by fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a controller action method which should handle a two-splitted form. Each form handles just a few properties of my Entity `Workflow`. After submitting the first form I can create and render the second form without problems. Now the problem:

After submitting the second form, the information of all values set in the first form are gone which means that when calling `submit` (or `handleRequest` does not make any difference here) the entity object only holds data of the properties set in the first form and it even can´t resolve some values properly.

Here is the Controller (with some comments):

```
public function createWorkflowAction(Request $request, Project $project, Workflow $workflow = null) {   

    if(!$workflow) {
        $workflow = new Workflow($project);
    }

    $firstFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowStatesType::class, $workflow);

    // $firstFormPart->handleRequest($request);
    $firstFormPart->submit($request->get($firstFormPart->getName()), false);

    $secondFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowTransitionsType::class, $workflow);
    // secondFormPart is created correct with all values after submitting $firstFormPart and calling submit

    if($firstFormPart->isSubmitted() && $firstFormPart->isValid()) {
        return $this->render('@MyBundle/Workflow/workflow_edit_create_second_part.html.twig', array(
            'form'   => $secondFormPart->createView(),
        ));
        // This will render correctly with all values submitted in the $firstFormPart
    }

    $secondFormPart->submit($request->get($secondFormPart->getName()), false);
    // $secondFormPart->handleRequest($request);
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM -> After submitting the $secondFormPart all property values set in the $firstFormPart are gone

    if($secondFormPart->isSubmitted() && $secondFormPart->isValid()) {
        dump($workflow);
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('@MyBundle/Workflow/workflow_edit_create_first_part.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $firstFormPart->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

`WorkflowStatesType`:

```
class WorkflowStatesType extends AbstractType {

        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata
         */
        private $classMetadata;

        /**
         * WorkflowType constructor.
         * @param EntityManager $em
         */

        public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
            $this->classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(Workflow::class);
        }

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder
                ->setMethod('PATCH')
                ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'nameTrans',
                    'attr'  => array('maxLength' => $this->classMetadata->getFieldMapping('name')['length']),
                ))
                ->add('states',  CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type'        => StateType::class,
                    'allow_add'         => true,
                    'error_bubbling'    => false,
                    'by_reference'      => false,
                    'label'             => 'workflowStatesTrans',
                ))
                ->add('next', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'nextFormPartTrans',
                ));
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class'            => Workflow::class,
                'translation_domain'    => 'My_Bundle',
            ));
        }

    }
```

---

`WorkflowTransitionsType`:

```
class WorkflowTransitionsType extends AbstractType {

        /**
         * @var Workflow
         */
        private $workflow;

        /**
         * @var Session
         */
        private $session;

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

            /** @var Workflow $workflow */
            $this->workflow = $options['data'];

                $builder
                    ->setMethod('PATCH')
                    ->add('initialState', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices'           => $this->workflow->getStates(),
                        'choice_label'      => function($state) {
                            return ($state && $state instanceof State) ? $state->getStatekey() : 'noVal';
                        },
                        'choice_value'      => function($state) {
                            return ($state && $state instanceof State) ? $state->getStatekey() : 'noVal';
                        },

                        // This combination of 'expanded' and 'multiple' implements a select box
                        'expanded'          => false,
                        'multiple'          => false,
                    ))
                    ->add('transitions', CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type'        => TransitionType::class,
                        'allow_add'         => true,
                        'allow_delete'      => true,
                        'error_bubbling'    => false,
                        'by_reference'      => false,
                        'label'             => 'transitionsTrans',
                        'entry_options'     => array(
                            'states'    => $this->workflow->getStates(),
                        ),
                    ))
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                        'label'             => 'submitTrans',
                    ));
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class'            => Workflow::class,
                'translation_domain'    => 'My_Bundle',
            ));
            $resolver->setRequired(array(
                'session'
            ));
        }
    }
```

How can I hold the property values of the `$workflow` submitted in the `$firstFormPart` when submitting the `$secondFormPart`?

Comment: Can you post both `PraWorkflowStatesType` and `PraWorkflowTransitionsType`? My guess is that `PraWorkflowTransitionsType` does not contain the fields of `PraWorkflowStatesType`, so after the second submit it can never have the data of the first form.

Comment: @JoryGeerts You are a genius! Hey Mcfly, what else could *Each form handles just a few properties of my Entity `Workflow`* mean? Of course the  `PraWorkflowTransitionsType` does not contain the fields of `PraWorkflowStatesType`! It is even part of the question title *Form model data loses property values which are* ***not represented by fields***.

Comment: @JoryGeerts Now you saying *after the second submit it can never have the data of the first form.*. Of course it can because I pass an object which contains all values necessary but Symfony won´t save these values after rendering the form which by the way is the main problem!

Comment: @JoryGeerts I added the Form classes anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the form is submitted again with only the secondForm data, you are losing the firstForm data.

You have 3 ways to keep them:

**1) Set the data from the firstForm into the query**

```
// Insert that instead of the `return $this->render` for the second form
$url = $this->generateUrl(
    $request->attributes->get('_route'),
    array_merge(
        $request->query->all(),
        array('secondForm' => true, 'name' => $workflow->getName(), 'states' => $workflow->getStates()) // change the param
    )
);
return $this->redirect($url);
```

Before `$secondFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowTransitionsType::class, $workflow);`

Set back the `name` and `states` into the `$workflow` entity, in this example you can check the query variable `secondForm` to know if the first form was submitted or not

**2) Set the data from the firstForm into the next PATCH request with some hidden field**

You have to modify the secondForm to handle the data from the firstForm with some [hidden form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html)

**3) Set the data in the session before returning the second form**

First of all, your entity will have to implement the interface `Serializable` and declare the method `serialize` and `unserialize`

like that

```
$this->get('session')->set('workflow', $workflow);
```

The method `serialize` will be used to store it.

You can set in back with the method `unserialize`

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$workflow = new Workflow();
$workflow->unserialize($session->get('workflow'));
```

Because you are storing the whole entity into the session, this solution will decrease a lot the performance of your application

Comment: 1. So there is no way that symfony takes care of HOLDING the object in a response/request cycle e.g. by adding hidden fields itself ? Thats the purpose of the question. 2. Did not now about the request query solution. 3. Adding hiddin fields is not very dynamic, because the entity and first form can change. 4. For some reason I don´t even need to use the Interface `Serializable` when storing the object in a session.

Comment: 1. No, because you are submitting 2 different requests, the second one is not aware of the first one, if you want to do that you have to submit the first data as well

2. I'll add it

3. In the second form, you can extend the first form and dynamically change the type to hidden (did not test it but theoretically, it should work)

4. Yes apparently, symfony has now a serializer to do the work for you :)

Comment: But the 3. point looks dirty, also what you can do is to maybe declare a getter in your entity which is getting an array of the firstForm data. Then you could use a subform like

    // In your secondFormType inside the `buildForm` method
    $builder->add('firstForm', FirstFormType::class);

With a `disable` or `hidden` option

Comment: I now added a solution I allready had (when lying about posting it the other day =D ) and it is quite something I was looking for because I do not have to change anything inside the controller. Everything happens regarding the form is inside the form. But I accept you answer because you came up with multiple, possible solution. (What I did not know is that I lose all 50 points when starting a bounty and doesn´t give them to anyone, then I would just start another bounty give you the 50 points. Next time I will be faster... :| )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property mapped. See [mapped property](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) or [allow_extra_fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields)

Comment: Hello, McFly?, the link you suggested says [`default: true`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) which means that in my case ALL FIELDS ARE MAPPED because I set `'mapped' => false` nowhere! Of course `allow_extra_fields` also does not change anything until I add some exra fields to hold the property values which I dislike more then my newly added [_unsatisfying solution_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601434/5233188)...

Comment: Don't need to be rude, it was just a long shot. I just tried to give you a direction, sorry. Question: why can't you nest the second form? If the values on the second aren't not null it should be satisfying. You can have two formtypes that uses tha same Entity. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

> ## *How can I hold the property values of the $workflow submitted in the $firstFormPart when submitting the $secondFormPart?*

So here is my (unsatisfying) solution:

1. I pass the current session as an option to my form class for the `$secondFormPart` which is the `WorkflowTransitionsType` class with passing it as an argument when calling `createForm` inside the Controller action method:

   ```
   $secondFormPart = $this->createForm(WorkflowTransitionsType::class, $workflow, array(
       'session'   => $this->get('session')
   ));
   ```
2. I save the session as a private property inside the `WorkflowTransitionsType` class, save the passed workflow in the current session and retrieve it when `buildForm` gets called a 2. time when submitting the form:

   ```
   class WorkflowTransitionsType extends AbstractType {

       /**
        * @var Workflow
        */
       private $workflow;

       /**
        * @var Session
        */
       private $session;

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

           /** @var Workflow $workflow */
           $this->workflow = $options['data'];

           /** @var Session $session */
           $this->session = $options['session'];

           // If the workflow is stored in the session we know that this method is called a 2. time!
           if($this->session->has($this->getBlockPrefix() . '_workflow')) $this->workflow = $this->session->get($this->getBlockPrefix() . '_workflow');

               $builder
                   ->setMethod('PATCH')
                   ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                       dump($event);
                       // This always gets called AFTER storing the workflow if it is present in the current session
                       $this->session->set($this->getBlockPrefix() . '_workflow', $this->workflow);
                   })
                   ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
                       // Here we manipulating the passed workflow data by setting all previous values! 
                       $eventForm = $event->getForm();

                       /** @var Workflow $submitWorkflow */
                       $submitWorkflow = $eventForm->getData();

                       $submitWorkflow->setName($this->workflow->getName());
                       foreach($this->workflow->getStates() as $state) $submitWorkflow->addState($state);

                       $eventForm->setData($submitWorkflow);
                   })
                   ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
                       // After submitting the workflow object is no longer required!
                       $this->session->remove($this->getBlockPrefix() . '_workflow');
                   })
                   ->add('initialState', ChoiceType::class, array(
                       ...
                       // Didn´t change (look at my question)
                   ))
                   ->add('transitions', CollectionType::class, array(
                       ...
                       // Didn´t change (look at my question)
                   ))
                   ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                       ...
                       // Didn´t change (look at my question)
                   ));
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array(
               'data_class'            => Workflow::class,
               'translation_domain'    => 'MyBundle',
           ));
           $resolver->setRequired(array(
               // This is necessary to prevent an error about an unknown option!
               'session'
           ));
       }
   }
   ```